# Как сделать порядок array по vote?

Tags: php, массивы

Сейчас:

```
Array
(
    [Dimata4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 6 минут назад
            [vote] => 3
        )

    [detractor] => Array
        (
            [date] => 9 часов назад
            [vote] => 6
        )

    [Smaill331] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20 часов назад
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [Dizic] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20 часов назад
            [vote] => 3
        )

)
```

А мне надо:

```
Array
(
    [detractor] => Array
        (
            [date] => 9 часов назад
            [vote] => 6
        )

    [Dimata4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 6 минут назад
            [vote] => 3
        )

     [Dizic] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20 часов назад
            [vote] => 3
        )

    [Smaill331] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20 часов назад
            [vote] => 2
        )

)
```

Как мне по [vote] делать порядок ?
Код который так делает:

```
foreach ($range as $key => $value) {
  $table = site::$site->Csql['user'];
  $user = site::$site->PDO->query("SELECT * FROM {$table['table']} WHERE id=? ",array($value['user']))[0];
  if ($ranges[$user['user']]){
    $ranges[$user['user']]['vote'] = $ranges[$user['user']]['vote'] + 1;
  }else {
    $ranges[$user['user']] = array("date"=> showDate($value['date']), "vote"=> 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php. Можно ещё применить сортировку в SQL запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array - ваш массив`

Пример раз:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ($a['vote'] - $b['vote']);
});
```

Пример 1.5 (PHP 7):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['vote'] <=> $b['vote'];
});
```

Пример два:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'vote'), SORT_DESC, $array);
```